# Does anyone use hg/git/svn for version control of PSDs/binary files?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial

I'm not dealing with 1-50 KB JPEGs, but 150-250+ MB psd files for various websites, and I'd like to keep track of the versions with a VCS.

If anyone has real world experience with such a scenario, could you please share? Which version control program do you use, and how is the binary support? How many files do you deal with on a day to day basis? What type of hosting do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say I mostly sill revision control text.  I strive to get as much information in text format as I can.  That said,  I have used svn to control binary data files for years.  No personal experience with your file format, but recently I've been mucking about alot in excel & access and especially for the access files they got quite large.  50MB was typical.  [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) has a very nice windows svn interface and and [NautilusSVN](http://code.google.com/p/nautilussvn/) is the linux/gnome equivalent.

The thing I like about revision control of excel files with TortoiseSVN will show you your differences between 2 excel files side by side.  Handy when you need it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe svn out of all the ones you listed handles binary files the best so far.
See http://subversion.tigris.org/features.html#binary-files

However, all of the new VCSes should be able to handle your workflow, so it's really a matter of choice.